# Where does null dereferencing cause invalid operation exceptions in Linq to entities queries?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Consider the three following cases of Entity Framework Core Linq to Entities statements:

1. Where statements outside of projections.

```cs
var results = context.Table.Where(t => t.NullableReference.BoolColumn);
```

2. Projections.

```cs
var results2 = context.Table.Select(t => t.NullableReference.BoolColumn).ToList();`
```

3. Projections containing where statements.

```cs
var results3 = context.Table
    .SelectMany(t => t.CollectionReference
        .Where(c => c.NullableReference.BoolColumn)
        .Select(c => c.TextColumn)
    )
    .ToList();
```

From the reproducible example I have provided, statement 1 does not cause an invalid operation exception and statement 2 does cause an invalid operation exception. Statement 3 does not cause an exception but I do not understand why.

Can anyone give an explanation of why for some statements null dereferencing is an issue, and for others it's not? Are there rules which determine whether or not a statement can experience an invalid operation exception?

See minimum reproducible example:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/i09bAo (Using in memory database)

https://dotnetfiddle.net/lEaqgb (Using sql server, will require running against a local instance using code first migrations)

To run the above please use the following commands in the package manager console after creating an empty database named EFCoreTest in a local server accessible with '.', further changes to the connection string may be required. Installing the referenced v6.0.26 nuget packages will also be required:

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
Update-Database
```

Comment: the (2) causes null dereference because the resulting list is expected to be `List<bool>` which doesnt accept `null`.

Comment: the (3) should work as both `null` and `false` on the `where` clause treated the same way: discarded

Comment: None of these LINQ queries should throw NRE exceptions. Everything that EF gets from theses queries is metainformation for building SQL and mapper.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Please see the minimum reproducible example, it shows your comment is incorrect.

Comment: @CallumBateson, ok, it is not right for `UseInMemoryDatabase` - which is fake provider. Do not use it for testing.

Comment: EF deals with *entities*, not tables and translates LINQ to SQL, or whatever language the underlying database uses. Talking about NREs suggests there's some confusion about both concepts.

Comment: The [in-memory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) is just a wrapper over a Dictionary, not a real database or DB emulator. It's only meant for simple quick&dirty checks. The docs goes to great lengths to stress this : `While some users use the in-memory database for testing, this is discouraged.` ,`The EF Core in-memory database is not designed for performance or robustness and should not be used outside of testing environments` , `New features are not being added to the in-memory database.`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have added a second example for you to run against a local instance of SQL Server. The issue is indeed still present.

Comment: @CallumBateson Please add the [mcve] to the question itself, not on an external site.

Answer (score 1):

Expressions in `Select()` or `Where()` are not evaluated in C# but instead "evaluated" in the database, or at least converted to a SQL query via LINQ to Entities. When you check the documentation [LINQ to Entities - Query Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities#query-conversion) you will see the following:

> In general, expressions in LINQ to Entities are evaluated on the server, so the behavior of the expression should not be expected to follow CLR semantics. For more information, see [Expressions in LINQ to Entities Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/expressions-in-linq-to-entities-queries).

This could explain why

```
context.Table1.Where(t => t.NullableNavigation.BoolColumn).ToList()
```

will not throw a `NullReferenceException`. From a C# standpoint it looks like a `NullReferenceException` (when you have such entities without the related `NullableNavigation` entity), but it works fine in LINQ to Entities and will generate an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT `t`.`Id`, `t`.`NullableNavigationId`
FROM `Table1` AS `t`
LEFT JOIN `Table2` AS `t0` ON `t`.`NullableNavigationId` = `t0`.`Id`
WHERE `t0`.`BoolColumn`
```

The other example

```
context.Table1.Select(t => t.NullableNavigation.BoolColumn).ToList();
```

will not throw a `NullReferenceException` as well. Again, the expression is "evaluated" in the database or converted via LINQ to Entities. This will generate an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT `t0`.`BoolColumn`
FROM `Table1` AS `t`
LEFT JOIN `Table2` AS `t0` ON `t`.`NullableNavigationId` = `t0`.`Id`
```

However, it will throw a `InvalidOperationException` later on (at least with "MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" in version 6.0.0) because this `SELECT` query can return `NULL` values when there is no related entity in the `Table2` table:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll: 'Nullable object must have a value.'
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_InvalidOperation_NoValue()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

as as result of

```
  System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value.
     at lambda_method17(Closure, QueryContext, DbDataReader, ResultContext, SingleQueryResultCoordinator)
     at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I’ve been seeing. I guess I should rephrase my question as to when invalid operations may occur? Is it only in projections, or would that be too much of a simplification?

Comment: @CallumBateson It will throw an `InvalidOperationException` in this case when a `null` value can "sneak" in into the result based on the generated SQL query. As an example, `context.Table1.Where(t => t.NullableNavigation.BoolColumn).Select(t => t.NullableNavigation.BoolColumn).ToList()` will not throw an `InvalidOperationException` even though projections are used.

Answer (score -1):

**None** of the above will throw `NullReferenceException`, because EF Core never executes them as-is. Rather, it uses these [expression trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/expression-trees/) as statements of intent, translates them into SQL which it executes on the underlying database, and returns the result.

Comment: Can you please explain the results shown in the minimum reproducible example? Is the top level projection expression not run on the result brought back by the SQL query, which I am aware is generated by examining the expression tree.

Comment: @CallumBateson it's not reproducible because it doesn't use a database at all. The in-memory provider is just a wrapper over a Dictionary. If you want to perform a real test, use a real database. Even if it's SQLite in in-memory mode

Comment: Please see my second example which can be run against a real SQL server instance.